# Friendly_Id - defining slug candidates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have a model called users, in which users have usernames. I have another model called educators, which has many users. I want to put friendly_ids on the educators model, and I want the slug to include the username (which is not referenced in the educator model). Is there a way that I can define the slug candidates on the educator model to take the username from the user model?  Many thanks.

Comment: What version of `friendly_id` are you using, and [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) I'll soon post an answer I think will help, but it would be easier to answer if I had some existing code to modify. :)

Comment: Also, an example of a specific `Educator` and the slug you want to achieve would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make the usernames available on the Educator model with a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) statement.

```
class Educator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :usernames, through: :users
end
```

Now I'm thinking you should be able to use `:usernames` in your slug candidates definition. I'm not entirely sure of how friendly_id will react on a collection, but there you have the main idea.

Also, if you wanted only a specific username but the model indeed `has_many :users` then you would need some more specific logic for sorting out which username you want.